# What is the best-practise way to store an append only series of files for streaming?

Tags: algorithm, directory, message-queue, nosql

What I want to do:

- Files arrive. Assume a file is a binary blob with a filename-legal name. Files are usually small.
- As the file arrives, it is assigned an ID. The file is stored on disk, keyed by the ID.
- The throughput and storage will be within the capabilities of a single server and hard disk, but too large and fast for trivial implementation. Storage is append-only, written files are never changed, but old files may be removed by the system to reclaim storage.
- The access mode of retrieving these files is "everything since this ID: ..." and consists of streaming files in the order they arrived. If given a blank ID, all known files will be streamed.
- If files are added after the request, they will also be streamed. After reaching the most recent file, the client can hold the connection open and wait for new files.
- For each file that is streamed, the client is told its ID. It is the client's job to keep track of what ID it last saw. That ID can be used to resume after a disconnect.
- It needs to handle multiple concurrent clients reading at different ID positions in the stream.

My questions:

1. Should I implement this myself? If so, **what would be the best practise way to do it**? Is is bad to rely on the filesystem and directories, would it be better to use aggregated files and an offset index? I am pretty sure it would be bad to try and put the data in an SQL database, they weren't designed for this sort of streaming reader.
2. Or is there an existing tool (NoSQL DB, message queue, etc) that does what I want above? Is it reliable and not a resource hog?

Answer (score 1):

In a way, this reminded me of FTP ;-)

An aggregated file would almost certainly run into the difficulty of (not) permitting multiple reads while a write goes on.

Individual files should be fine - I know of nothing in a (Linux) file system that shouldn't let you implement this in an efficient way. Of course, something must be done to achieve the required level of safety (RAID or...?)

Alternating between ID messages and file data messages requires a protocol that's capable of handling some contingencies, signals "end of data", etc. Or: Is it impossible that "removal of old files" clashes with an "all known files" request?

Comment: I think that the "read while write" problem in aggregated files is resolved by (1) always appending, never going back to change what has been written, and (2) using length prefixed data. So trailing half-written garbage can be ignored - it will be too short.

Comment: I was thinking the protocol would be rather like a series of HTTP responses - result code, headers (name, ID, content-length), data, repeat. Error result codes would include "the ID you asked for has been purged to save space".

Comment: The length prefix will help to discover an incomplete blob. But how and when will the reader continue, with obsolete data in its buffer? - HTTP is OK, lots of packages around.

Comment: The reader won't be sent incomplete data, and, if the reader reads a partial datum and then gets a disconnect (someone unplugged the internet), it will just reconnect and ask for "messages since <ID of the last valid message>". The only place partial data could exist is in the on-disk storage. Readers don't read the storage directly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use one huge file to store the data and another file to store the offsets.  The appender can open it for write and the server process(es) open it for read.  You may want to length-delimit the data chunks in order to aid recovery if something goes wrong.

Storing each chunk in a separate file on the fs will most likely end in tears.  Tears and elevated latency.  For one thing, accessing the next file in sequence means you have to do a metadata lookup.  For another, I don't believe Linux's block layer will fetch the next file in sequence from disk before you ask it to.

Comment: If it's in big files like that, I'd probably start a new file every day or something, to make cleaning up old data easier. Either the whole file is present or none of it is, and the newest file only ever grows, no file ever shrinks (this means that seek offsets are stable).

Comment: Just blow holes in it with whatever-that-`ioctl`'s-called.  Sparse file support is your friend.

Comment: That sounds like it would slow things down and/or confuse the OS, if you try to clean up a file by putting holes in it rather than segmenting it and deleting segments as units.

Comment: I haven't had trouble with it.  The file will start at an offset that isn't 0, and that's no big deal.  Segmenting is of course also workable.

Comment: Eventually you will have to reorganize. - Don't forget that metadata (=index node) levels increase when the file grows. - Consider individual files (which should require less code) for a prototype, and benchmark. There's no point in being faster on the disk than you need to be on the line.